# SpringBoot resource versioning failing due to null ResourceUrlProvider in ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.resolveUrlPath

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a fairly plain Spring Boot 2.3.3 application created straight from the fine articles at various popular tutorial sites.

I want to enable **static resource versioning**. This is a standard problem in web development - if you are not familiar with static resource versioning, please look it up before attempting to interpret my question.

So I have this in my `WebConfig` class:

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean<?> resourceUrlEncodingFilterRegistration() {
    FilterRegistrationBean<ResourceUrlEncodingFilter> registration = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
    registration.setFilter(new ResourceUrlEncodingFilter());
    registration.addUrlPatterns("/*");
    return registration;
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/clientlibs/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/clientlibs/", "classpath:/")
            .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(1, TimeUnit.HOURS))
            .resourceChain(true)
            .addResolver(new VersionResourceResolver()
                    .addContentVersionStrategy("/**"))
            .addTransformer(new CssLinkResourceTransformer());
}
```

And this in my `web.xml`:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>resourceUrlEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlEncodingFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>resourceUrlEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>servletSpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

And this in my `spring-context.xml`:

```
<mvc:resources location="/clientlibs/" mapping="/clientlibs/**" />
```

And for good measure, I also have this `application.properties`:

```
# Enable HTML5 application cache manifest rewriting.
spring.resources.chain.html-application-cache=true

# Enable the Spring Resource Handling chain. Disabled by default unless at least one strategy has been enabled.
spring.resources.chain.enabled=true
# Enable the content Version Strategy.
spring.resources.chain.strategy.content.enabled=true
# Comma-separated list of patterns to apply to the Version Strategy.
spring.resources.chain.strategy.content.paths=/**
```

My static resources are located in `WEB-INF`, but I also tried moving them to `src/main/resources`, for no change in behaviour.

Oh, and this pattern is seen in my `template.html`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/clientlibs/styles/custom/_global.css}" href="../../../clientlibs/styles/custom/_global.css"/>
```

So here the **expected behaviour** is that my resources would be versioned - the reference to `_global` in the example above would be rendered with a hex string.

But the **actual behaviour** is that *nothing happens*. There are no warnings, no errors, but also the `_global.css` is spit out to the browser unmodified.

So I did some deep investigation by stepping through the Spring Framework code in the debugger. I found this in `ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.class`:

```
    @Nullable
    public String resolveUrlPath(String url) {
        if (this.resourceUrlProvider == null) {
            logger.trace("ResourceUrlProvider not available via request attribute " +
                    ResourceUrlProviderExposingInterceptor.RESOURCE_URL_PROVIDER_ATTR);
            return null;
        }
        if (this.indexLookupPath != null && url.startsWith(this.prefixLookupPath)) {
            int suffixIndex = getEndPathIndex(url);
            String suffix = url.substring(suffixIndex);
            String lookupPath = url.substring(this.indexLookupPath, suffixIndex);
            lookupPath = this.resourceUrlProvider.getForLookupPath(lookupPath);
            if (lookupPath != null) {
                return this.prefixLookupPath + lookupPath + suffix;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Where I found that the `this.resourceUrlProvider == null` is what's happening.

Assuming this is the root cause of my problem, why is it null and how can I fix it?

*STRANGE THINGS*

If I change to `.resourceChain(false)`, then the solution partially works - versioning is present on the outbound links, but inbound is not recognized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave up trying to use the spring framework solution for this. I have gone through every possible tutorial, SO question, Spring documentation, step through Spring code, etc. Nothing works.

Finally implemented a custom solution in a simple filter:

```
package ctc.front.web.util;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper;

import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils;
import org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean;

public class SimpleResourceVersioningFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    // location of static resources in the public URL 
    private static final String RESOURCE_URL_PREFIX = "/clientlibs/";

    // location of static resources in the classpath
    private static final String RESOURCE_CLASSPATH_PREFIX = "/static/";

    private static final Map<String,String> hashCache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        filterChain.doFilter(request,
                new Wrapper((HttpServletResponse) response));
    }

    private static class Wrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {

        Wrapper(HttpServletResponse wrapped) {
            super(wrapped);
        }

        @Override
        public String encodeURL(String url) {
            if (url.startsWith(RESOURCE_URL_PREFIX)) {
                return url + "?" + hashCache.computeIfAbsent(url, key -> {
                    try (InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader()
                            .getResourceAsStream(RESOURCE_CLASSPATH_PREFIX + url)) {
                        if (is == null) {
                            throw new FileNotFoundException(url);
                        }
                        return DigestUtils.sha1Hex(is);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                });
            } else
                return url;
        }
    }
}
```

This solution appends the version to the query string, so it's not necessary to implement any kind of un-filtering on the inbound requests. Adjust your CDN cache configurations accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Springboot (v2.4.2) project with Thymeleaf, also with spring security. This is what I did to enable resource versioning or cache buster.

in my `application.yaml` file added

```
spring:
  web:
    resources:
      chain:
        enabled: true
        strategy:
          content:
            enabled: true
            paths: /**/*.js,/**/*.css,/js/**,/css/**,/icon/**
```

and added a configuration to enable `ResourceUrlEncodingFilter` as Bean.

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ConditionalOnEnabledResourceChain;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlEncodingFilter;

@Configuration
public class CacheBusterMVCConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnEnabledResourceChain
    public ResourceUrlEncodingFilter resourceUrlEncodingFilter() {
        return new ResourceUrlEncodingFilter();
    }
}
```

and have this in my `SecurityConfig`

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
    web.ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/js/**", "/css/**", "/icon/**", "/webjars/**");
}
```

Now, I can see version for static resource.

```
<link href="/webjars/bulma/0.9.1/css/bulma.min-281a08362e797a0922f6074359ad15be.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/webjars/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min-c4af24ce595437830af0a401897698b2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/icon/favicon-32x32-9ff600ad27cf43113130456752dc2ef6.png" rel="icon" sizes="32x32" type="image/png"/>
<link href="/icon/favicon-16x16-9501d9cfa7e2976c8bb3dd745d2bd503.png" rel="icon" sizes="16x16" type="image/png"/>
```